# Parsing json strings without quotation mark should throw exception in gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse a very simple json snippet:

```
{ key : "value" }
```

Since json requires to have quotation marks around strings i would expect Gson (2.2.4) to throw an exception when parsing that snippet. That is not the case in fact the `key` is treated like a regular string.

The same also happens for the following snippet which clearly looks broken:

```
{ key" : "value" }
```

Gson uses the `key"` as the key in the produced map. Is there any way to tell gson to be more strict about the string parsing?

Comment: Maybe your parser set to lenient mode? http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient(boolean)

Comment: I have explicitly played around with lenient mode on my Reader. Weather it is lenient or not did not make a difference.